# Arc transitions with multiple doughnuts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization

I'm trying to get transitions for multiple doughnuts contained in div with id "donut" as the data is updated.
 
I have an array of data :

```
  self.data = {
        counts: [35, 10, 60, 21],
        hours: [22, 66, 10, 120],
        secs: [1, 1, 1, 1]
    };
```

I have the global values setup as follows:

```
   var width = 134,
   height = 134,
   cwidth = 20;
   var color = d3.scale.category20();
```

I setup the multiple doughnuts using this function:

```
self.setupFanChart = function() {

       self.pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .sort(null);

        self.arc = d3.svg.arc();
        self.svg = d3.select("#donut")
                .append("svg").attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
        self.gs = self.svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(self.data)).enter().append("g");
        self.path = self.gs.selectAll("path")
                .data(function(d) {
                    return self.pie(d);
                })
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                })
                .attr("d", function(d, i, j) {
                    return self.arc.innerRadius(20 + cwidth * j).outerRadius(15 + cwidth * (j + 1))(d);
                })
                .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles;


        self.svg.append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("class", "inside")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return '56%';
                });
        self.svg.append("text")
                .attr("dy", "2em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("class", "data")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return 'some text';
                });


    };
```

this gets updated after every 10 seconds using an api call, when I call the update function:

```
self.updateFanChart = function(data,color) {
        self.gs = self.svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(data));
        self.pie=self.pie.value(function(d) { return d; }); 
        self.path = self.gs.select("path")
                .data(self.pie)
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                })
                .attr("d", function(d, i, j) {
                    return self.arc.innerRadius(20 + cwidth * j).outerRadius(15 + cwidth * (j + 1))(d);
                })
                .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles;


        self.svg.append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("class", "inside")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return '56%';
                });
        self.svg.append("text")
                .attr("dy", "2em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("class", "data")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return 'some text';
                });
        self.data = {
            counts: [1, 1, 1, 1],
            hours: [1, 1, 1, 1],
            secs: [1, 1, 1, 1]
        };
```

The multiple doughnuts get created with the initial value, but the update of values doesn't take place, I can see they get updated correctly in the watch debugger,I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined d3.min.js:4n d3.min.js:4pa.data d3.min.js:3self.updateFanChart
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example please, e.g. on jsfiddle?

Comment: got it to work :I wasn't selecting all teh paths:
        self.path = self.gs.selectAll("path")
                .data(self.pie)
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                })
                .attr("d", function(d, i, j) {
                    return self.arc.innerRadius(20 + cwidth * j).outerRadius(15 + cwidth * (j + 1))(d);
                })
                .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles;